# Python3: How to remove list items with another list item(s)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
     a = ['eggs', 'eggs', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
```

and:

```
     b = ['e', 'e']
```

I want to be able to remove eggs from list a. 
According to the e's in list b.
so my ideal output would be:

```
     a = ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
```

Since there is only 2 e's in list a.

I have tried:

```
     [a.remove('eggs') for e in b if e =='e' for eggs in a if eggs=='eggs']
```

The problem is that that this list-comprehension removes all eggs.
show me the pythonic way!

Comment: Can you please explain your logic? Are you looking to remove the first two items in `a` beginning with "e"? Will list `b` always consist of a single letter *n* times?

Comment: @jpp There are two e’s in list b so I would like to remove “eggs” in list a depending on how many e’s in list b

Comment: @D.Vidal jpp's more pressing question is - are these `'e'`s completely arbitrary strings and you only concern yourself with `'eggs'` for some reason? Or are they matching the first character in `'eggs'`? Your problem statement is rather fuzzy.

Comment: @miradulo Yes these are arbitrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `lst.remove` in a list comprehension. Since this method mutates your list and returns `None`, you are not interested in the output and should use a for-loop instead.

You can use `lst.count` to find out the number of occurences of `'e'` in your second list and then use `lst.remove` on the second list.

```
a = ['eggs', 'eggs', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
b = ['e', 'e']

for _ in range(b.count('e')):
    a.remove('eggs')

print(a) # ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['eggs', 'eggs', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
b = ['e', 'e']

for e in b:
    if e == "e":
        a.remove("eggs")

print(a)
```

This is not one line but it should work.